# How can I stop the code from executing the next line after RunWorkerAsync until it finishes?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, backgroundworker

My VB.NET (WPF) application has drop-down lists with names of states and their cities. I use a loop to iterate through a selected state and its cities and I perform some functions regarding the cities. I check N number of webpages for every city in the loop and populate a Datagrid with some results using a **BackGroundWorker**.

However, since I am using a **backgroundworker** in the loop, it is executed and sent to the background and the code keeps moving forward. I need the code to wait until **backgroundworker (RunWorkerAsync)** is finished to move onto the next line. It works perfectly when I use it for one city, but when I use it in a loop for a list of cities, it just keeps executing the next lines after backgroundworker and the loop keeps going on.

I have researched this before and the only option that the solutions gave me was to introduce a RunWorkerCompleted in the code. That would mean that I will have to split my code in two parts and place the stuff I want to be executed afterward in the **RunWorkerCompleted**. Would that work in a loop? Here's some PseudoCode:

```
For i as integer = 0 to cityCount

Dim city as string = cbCity.SelectedValue.ToString()
worker.RunWorkerAsync
worker.RunWorkerCompleted
cbCity.SelectedIndex += 1

Next
```

Here's the thing. Wouldn't the above PseudoCode run the **worker.RunWorkerCompleted** while **worker.RunWorkerAsync** is still running? Will it wait for **worker.RunWorkerAsync** to be completed and finished and then execute **worker.RunWorkerCompleted**? I am using BackgroundWorker to fill the UI without freezing it and the city variable is being updated in every iteration and used inside RunWorkerAsync. So, essentially, I am trying to execute worker.RunWorkerAsync completely and then move onto the next line and continue the loop.

I am sorry if my language doesn't make sense. I have researched about this and tried several methods, and I am here because none of them worked. I can't share the complete code due to some copyrights issues, but I will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: If you need to wait then there's no point in using BGW, you might as well run the code directly.  Proper usage is indeed to move whatever code you have that needs the job to be completed into the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  If you want it cleaner with everything in one place then you need to switch to Task and use async/await.

Comment: RunWorkerCompleted is called automatically when RunWorkerAsync has finished (see [BackgroundWorker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8)). It seems to me that the loop should be in the BGW, along with the code you want to run at the end of each iteration.

Comment: ... Note that the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netframework-4.8) can take an Object as its second parameter, so if you make a suitable Class to pass, you can send anything you want to the ProgressChanged handler.

Comment: @HansPassant I cannot eliminate BGW because the code doesn't update the UI properly and constantly freezes the UI while updating the datagrid. Moverover, the Async/Wait will just make the thread sleep and still cause the UI to freeze. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AndrewMorton That actually is worth a try. I can move the entire code (loop) inside the BGW and see if that solves the problem. That actually may work. Thank you. I will try that in a while. However, do you have any suggestions for making the existing code wait until the BGW is done?

Comment: @AndrewMorton As far as ProgressChanged handler is concerned, I don't think that will work. Every loop updates the same Datagrid on the UI. If I use that, it will just keep changing the UI too fast since the BGW will never stop running and start several threads for the same UI

Comment: @Namechangedtomaskidentity You mustn't update UI elements directly from the BGW. You don't have to report progress on every iteration, you could do it every, say, 50th iteration, and after the last iteration, or whatever makes it look good.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I wish that were the case. I already did that. I used to collect the information in a local Datatable and update the UI every 25th iteration. My boss says that he wants to see something happen on screen and the UI must update every iteration. I actually wrote the code in Parallel and made it faster, but now I have to update the UI every other second so that the app looks "interesting"

Comment: @AndrewMorton Your suggestion worked. I have new errors now, but your suggestion worked. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I placed the entire code inside the BGW, and now it waits for the functions to finish executing before moving onto the next line of code. This was your suggestion in your first comment and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RunWorkerCompleted is called automatically when RunWorkerAsync has finished (please see the [BackgroundWorker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8) documentation).

The loop should be in the BGW, along with the code you want to run at the end of each iteration.

---

(Note that the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=netframework-4.8) can take an Object as its second parameter, so if you make a suitable Class to pass, you can send anything you want to the ProgressChanged handler.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this can be your alternative or not:

```
'Iteration Sub
Private Sub MyStatus()
    'Here your code iteration
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10000
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * i / 10000))
        If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub

'For begin and stop Async
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    Try
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

'To Call the iteration
Private Sub bw1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    MyStatus()
End Sub

'To Monitor the progress
Private Sub bw1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

'If any information need to indicate that the iteration is complete
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
End Sub
```